# Get tag of view within a ListView item layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-xml

I have the following layout which is used in a ListView (meaning it's used once for each item in the list):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/stats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="10 comments"
            android:tag="10"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/stats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="increaseComments"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If a user clicks on the `ImageView`, I want to change the text of the `TextView` to "11 comments" (increment it). Given the onClick method of the `ImageView` below, how can I get the tag of the `TextView` and then use it to change the text of the `TextView`?

```
public void increaseComments(View view) {
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: Where is the ListView itself?

Comment: make a Google search before asking this kind of questions. You will find your answer less than 1 minute. `(int) imageView.getTag()`

Comment: @osayilgan Reread the question. I'm asking how do I get the tag of the `TextView` if I click on the `ImageView` in the onClick method I provided...

Comment: @AlexK It's not necessary for me to provide the ListView (`<ListView> ... </ListView>`) layout. The list **item** layout is given in my question, however.

Comment: @user5477909 see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set & get the Tag of your Views with `getTag()` and `setTag(tagObject)` methods. See the [android developer reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()) for more information.

You can apply `getTag()` method to any of your View Objects in your layout. If you have set something in your `XML` or in your code, you can get the `TAG` but it's an Object so it requires Class Casting.

e.g, in your case, `int textViewTag = (int)total.getTag()`

**EDIT**

This is pretty much like a pseudo code to give you the idea. This not the ideal way of handling your `getView` method of your adapter. Refer to [this blog](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) to have more understanding about `ListViews`, `ViewHolder` Pattern and `Adapters`.

```
    /* Somewhere in your adapter class, define them Globally */
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView total;

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = yourActivityInstance.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_list_item_xml, parent, false);

        imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        total = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.total);

        return convertView;
    }

    /**
     * Called when the ImageView is Clicked.
     */
    public void increaseComments() {

        /* There you have the Tag of your Text View */
        int textViewTag = (int) total.getTag();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my question. Look at the onClick method of the `ImageView` (`increaseComments()`). From **within that method**, how can I get the tag of the `TextView` in the layout?

Comment: @user5477909 when you inflate your item layout in your `getView()` method of your adapter class, you will need to hold references to your `TextView`, then you can access to it's Tag.